# How do I get Sql Server CE to start identity from 1?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce

I cant use truncate table in sql server CE (annoyingly) so I use:

```
drop table mytable
```

However when I re-insert rows the Ids pick up where they left off. Is there any way to start the Id's from scratch again?

Comment: read my comment, just read CHECKIDENT is not available in CE edition, just issue an ALTER TABLE statement and alter the ID identity value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Enter `DBCC CHECKIDENT`:</strike>

> Checks the current identity value for the specified table and, if it
>   is needed, changes the identity value.

Usage:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('HumanResources.Employee', RESEED, 30)
GO
```

In your case

```
Use YourDBName
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT('YourTableName', RESEED, 0)
GO
```

Replace YourDBName with your database name, and replace YourTableName with the name of your table, and reseed the value, the last parameter (the 0 in this case) will reseed your ID to that value.

## Edit

Just read that DBCC CHECKIDENT is not available in CE edition.

In this case use `ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN ID Identity (999, 1)`

(999 is the new max of the ID column)...